# How to get long value(poId) from position onitemclick and pass by intent onitemclick in listview(Closed)

Tags: android, listview

i'm new on android and stackoverflow so if i done some mistake in my question then please guide me.my problem is when i click on item of my listview then every item shows same content on next activity.i have many items in listview and i want to send poId on next activity using intent on click item of list but when i click on any item of list then poId is same(which is last like i have 3 items then getting poId of 3rd item on every item of listview) on every item of list.please tell me how can i get clickable poId and send on next activity using intent of that position my code is here please guide me and help also:

```
   lstPo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(POListActivity.this, PODetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("poId",poId);
                startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

this is my asynctask where from i get poId

```
 private class GetPoList extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ContentValues param= new ContentValues();
        param.put("buyerId", buyerId);
        JSONObject rootObj = parser.makeHttpRequest(Constants.URL_GET_PO_LIST, "GET", param);
        try {

            if (rootObj != null) {
                String status = rootObj.getString(Constants.SvcStatus);
                Log.d("Status",status);
                if (Constants.Success.equals(status)) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(rootObj));
                    Log.d("PO_List ", jsonObject.toString());
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("lstPO");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        poId = object.getLong("poId");
                        poNo = object.getString("poNo");
                        deliveryDt = object.getString("deliveryDt");
                        metersCompleted = object.getInt("metersCompleted");
                        totalMeters = object.getInt("totalMeters");
                        comments = object.getString("comments");
                        hideStatus = object.getInt("hideStatus");
                        poListData = new PO(poNo, deliveryDt, metersCompleted, totalMeters, comments,hideStatus);
                        poListAdapter.add(poListData);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(POListActivity.this, "not Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String string){
        super.onPostExecute(string);
        lstPo.setAdapter(poListAdapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If PO class does't have poId add it.

Change PO class constructor to accept poId as parameter.

Add a getter for poId to PO class.

In doInBackground method pass poId as parameter where you make a new instance of PO class.

```
poListData = new PO(poId, poNo, deliveryDt, metersCompleted, totalMeters, comments,hideStatus);
```

in onItemClickListener use this:

```
 lstPo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            PO current = (PO) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(POListActivity.this, PODetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("poId",current.getPoId());
            startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are really near the solution. The problem is that you set poId inside a `for loop`. So the value will be the last iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    //poId will be override after each iteration
    poId = object.getLong("poId");

    poNo = object.getString("poNo");
    deliveryDt = object.getString("deliveryDt");
    metersCompleted = object.getInt("metersCompleted");
    totalMeters = object.getInt("totalMeters");
    comments = object.getString("comments");
    hideStatus = object.getInt("hideStatus");
    poListData = new PO(poNo, deliveryDt, metersCompleted, totalMeters, comments,hideStatus);
    poListAdapter.add(poListData);
}
```

So my solution is to store poId inside array list:

```
// a class member
List<Long> poIds = new ArrayList<>();
```

And in your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    //save ids inside List
    poIds.add(object.getLong("poId"));

    poNo = object.getString("poNo");
    deliveryDt = object.getString("deliveryDt");
    metersCompleted = object.getInt("metersCompleted");
    totalMeters = object.getInt("totalMeters");
    comments = object.getString("comments");
    hideStatus = object.getInt("hideStatus");
    poListData = new PO(poNo, deliveryDt, metersCompleted, totalMeters, comments,hideStatus);
    poListAdapter.add(poListData);
}
```

Finally in the listener:

```
stPo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(POListActivity.this, PODetailsActivity.class);
        //retrieve correct poId here
        intent.putExtra("poId",poIds.get(position));
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Comment: i didn't try this because i have done solution but thank you sir to try solve my problem...